# How to Renew credentials in Aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-dynamodb

We have been fighting an issue with renewing credentials.

We have a Aws Unity Sdk for Dynamodb  API that get a token from cognito from AWs backend. The initial login works fine, we get a token, use it in SDK, get credentials and have access to AWS ressources.

It is working for first 4 days.After about 3-4 dayss, we loose access to ressources, I assume STS credential expire.

At that point, we can not do anything unless with force stop, or clear data. If we logout, and re-login, still, does not work. It is like past expired credentials are somehow saved forever.

Any idea? What do we need to do after credentials expire?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code? How you obtain the token? And what message are you receiving after those 3-4 days?